# Камера не двигается за персонажем

Tags: c#, unity3d

код:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class cameraController : MonoBehaviour
{
     public float dumping = 1.5f;
     public Vector2 offset = new Vector2(2f, 1f);
     public bool isLeft;
     private transform Player;
     private int lastX;

     void Start(){
       offset = new Vector2(Mathf.Abs(offset.x), offset.y);
       FindPlayer(isLeft);
     }
  public void FindPlayer(bool playerisLeft)
  {
    player = GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag("Player").transform;
    lastX = Mathf.RoundToInt(player.position.x);
    if (playerisLeft) {
      transform.position = new Vector3(player.position.x - offset.x, player.position.y - offset.y, transform.position.z);
    }else {
      transform.position = new Vector3(player.position.x + offset.x, player.position.y + offset.y, transform.position.z);
    }
  }
  void Update(){
    if (player) {
      int currentX = Mathf.RoundToInt(player.position.x);
      if (currentX > lastX) isLeft = false; else if (currentX < lastX) isleft = true;
      lastX = Mathf.RoundToInt(player.position.x);

      Vector3 target;
      if (isLeft) {
        target = new Vector3(player.position.x - offset.x, player.position.y - offset.y, transform.position.z);
      }
      else {
        target = new Vector3(player.position.x + offset.x, player.position.y + offset.y, transform.position.z);
      }

      Vector3 currentPosition = Vector3.Lerp(transform.position, target, dumping * Time.deltaTime );
      transform.position = currentPosition;
    }
  }
}
```

ошибка:

```
The type or namespace name 'transform' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

Answer (score 1):

transform - свойство 
Transform - тип 
И дело не в большой букве, а во внимательности

```
private transform Player;//заменить
private Transform Player;
```

Comment: но ведь Transform это класс...

Comment: @Methorn класс - пользовательский тип данных, ели вопрос в этом

Answer (score 0):

Честно говоря, мне не очень нравятся такие вопросы, в которых даже нет вступления. Дана проблема, код, ошибка. Вы даже не написали в какой строке ошибка! Ну ладно, у вас не очень высокий опыт на StackVerflow, так что простительно.

Поподробнее разъясню ответ Valera Kvip.

[Transform](https://docs.unity3d.com/ru/530/Manual/class-Transform.html) - это тип данных, как int, string, GameObject и так далее. Это один из основных компонентов, который есть у всех игровых объектов. Он включает в себя такие поля, как позиция XYZ, вращение XYZ, размер XYZ.

[transform](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/GameObject-transform.html) - это *функция* с помощью которой вы можете получить компонент Transform игрового объекта. Синтаксис: Игровой_объект.transform.
Полученное значение можно упаковать в переменную, типа данных Transform.

ТАКИМ ОБРАЗОМ. Чтобы исправить ошибку вам нужно в 10 строке заменить

```
private transform Player;
```

на

```
private Transform Player;
```

Comment: А за что мне собственно поставили минусы? Я подробно разъяснил ответ Valera, потому что он ничего не рассказал и не объяснил, дал ссылки на официальную документацию на русском языке, объяснил все своими словами, порекомендовал задавшему вопрос добавлять в вопрос хоть какую-то преамбулу, дал СОВЕТ новому пользователю... Не вижу ни одного пункта, которым руководствуются ставящие минусы. Видимо сработал принцип 'Я лучше всех, все остальные дураки'... Хорошо -_-

Answer (score 0):

Что бы камера двигалась за персонажем вообще не нужно никакого кода. Ни строчки.

Достаточно просто разместить в инспекторе обьект камеры внутрь обьекта персонажа после чего визуально отстроить положение камеры в пространстве. И все, камера будет следовать за персонажем.

---

Что до ошибки, то она явно указывает на то, что ты неправильно использовал transform.

А еще желательно поработать над неймингом переменных ибо сейчас все только заплутывает.